# Converting partition from basic to dynamic in Windows Server 2022 gives security error

Tags: windows, raid, hard-drive

The server has 2 1 TB SSD drives, meant to be in RAID1 on the OS level, using Windows Disk Management, or Diskpart.

We have over one hundred of servers with this configuration which were installed with no problem but mostly these are HDD, not SSD.

When I install the system on a clean drive and then try to mirror this drive to the second one (Disk 0 -> Disk 1), I have to first make it dynamic and that is where it fails with an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqnJB.png)

In DC, they tried different drive firmwares, changing sector sizes, capacity (reportedly 3 technicians tried to solve this).
I tried it with MBR and also GPT partition table, install the system to the second drive and mirror it to the first one, converting the drives to dynamic prior to the OS installation, reformatting the drives but no success. The security which Windows is complaining about is that you cannot convert System partition to dynamic but looks like on some drives it works, on some not. Last week I got a server with the same drives, OS and in the end replacing the drives helped to overcome this error but now, these are the 3rd set of drives that we are trying and still nothing.
Does anyone have an experience with this? It looks like an OS issue where Windows either locks the drives somehow in the installation process (mounted Windows ISO problem?) or there could be something wrong with the drives I just cannot figure out what.
This is the desirable state:
[desirable state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzE0A.png)

Comment: Dynamic Disks are a dead end technology and has been deprecated from Windows for several years. This is something that may fail when needed most and leave the next unlucky bag holder in a jackpot. You should consider a hardware RAID controller.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk

Comment: Thank you for your response. We know it is not recommended to use it but now, we do not feel the need to use HW RAID as OS RAID is sufficient for our use and also way cheaper. It is about finding the right balance and we are leaning towards this solution. It works on all other servers, even the new ones we recently got. My question is if someone knows why does it work on some drives and on some not.

Comment: You're looking for someone that has experienced the same problem. The problem with that expectation is there are now *very few* users of Dynamic Disks. You may actually be the expert in this narrow subject. There also aren't m/any third party disk utilities that work with Dynamic Disks. A particularly bad choice of technology, like a rat trap inside a bear trap in a minefield. But that's just like my opinion.

Comment: You need to disable secure boot in BIOS/UEFI. It should be possible to reenable it afterwards. Otherwise, let it deactivated, if it's no problem for you.

Comment: This does not work either as the server which refused to convert disks to dynamic has secure boot disabled. Also BIOS was not touched on any server and some disks worked, some not. For this case the solution was to try different sets of disks and aswell as in other cases, we found that one set worked and is used now. However this is not a solution, still.